# Showing questionmark icon on every file in solution explorere in VS 2012-SVN

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, tortoisesvn

I am using Tortoise SVN in VS 2012. 
There are total 3 users which are using the same solution and using SVN.
one of the user added new files in project and when I take latest version of the the solution 
it showing question mark icon in front of every newly added file. 
whats the issue ?

Comment: TortoiseSVN is a standalone Subversion client, a Windows shell extension. What exactly did you use to "see" it in Visual Studio? VisualSVN? OR some minor manual VS customization?

Comment: Well, I am new user of it. I am still learning it. I have installed Tortoise SVN. The regular commit and update with existing Files are work fine. but if I want to add any folder to solution it not showing in proper manner. It showing either cross mark icon or question mark icon in front of the newly added file.

Comment: so you've added a folder to the solution, but you didn't add it to SVN. You need to manually add it through TortoiseSVN context menu. Since you already use TortoiseSVN you can consider using VisualSVN to automate tasks like this and get other SVN features right inside the IDE: http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/.

Comment: ya, I have already using the SVN Tool of VS2012. what is the proper way to add the folder in the solution and how it will reflect in subversion source DB. ? I cant find step by step process. How to add to subversion using context menu.

Comment: "SVN Tool of VS2012"? What?

Comment: Are you using AnkhSVN? VisualSVN? Or other integration tool with VS2012?

Answer (score 1):

Simply right-click on the file(s) and select

```
Tortise Svn → Add(to subversion) → OK
```